# Map tiles flicker between terrain and normal types

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

I have a Google Maps v2 application. During rendering, the map tiles flicker between terrain-type and normal-type. You can see the tile boundaries in the screenshot below. Each tile seems to flicker between the two types, then settles on one.

Panning or zooming sets off the whole flickering again. Some tiles seem to be more prone to the flickering than others, but it's not predictable or consistent.

The map is set to terrain-type:

```
 map.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
```

This happens both on my Android 4.1 phone, and an Android 4.4 Nexus 7. I've only noticed it recently, so it may have crept in during the last update to Google Play Services (currently using update 13). Upgrading to update 15 makes no difference, the flickering continues.

Has anyone else see this behaviour before?

[image]

Comment: I had some similar issues in the past. During sliding the map out to the left, the map itself started to flicker. In the end, we had to put an invisible `LinearLayout` over the whole map and set the focus on it  and removed it after the transistion. (I couldn't find the related blog post). Might not solve your issue, but just for the record...

Comment: If this is only for your app, I'd suggest you add a ViewTreeObserver to your map, and in it change the map type. If this problem persists from inside, I do not think your problem is from your software. If everything works fine, though... You might be doing something wrong.

Comment: Could you add the map related code ?

Comment: This seems to be an internal Google Maps bug. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6345)

Comment: I've seen this behaviour, but only on poor internet and during debugging. Can you confirm these two things aren't the case right now?

Comment: Did you try to disable / enable "Turn off hardware overlay" under developer options. I wonder if this make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Problem has been fixed as of google-play-services v16.

Sadly it's a [Known Problem](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6345) and I expect it might be fixed soon; That being said, there are [multiple issues with tiles in maps v2](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=1&q=label%3aApiType-Android2%20tiles&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&cells=tiles).

As per this issue, you might be able to avoid the flickering with manually setting a `TileOverlay` and using `clearTileCache()` instead. The clear caveat here would be that you, for entire moments, lose the entire data you have and might see blanks as clearing the cache is on the spot and will not consider specific parts or clearing only upon new fetches.

[**TileOverlay**](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay.html) docs state:

> The **TileProvider** provides the images that are used in the tile overlay. You must specify the tile provider before it is added to the map. The tile provider cannot be changed once it has been added; however, you can modify the behavior of the tile provider to return different images for specific coordinates. If the tiles provided by the tile provider change, you must call **clearTileCache()** afterwards to ensure that the previous tiles are no longer rendered.

Another option, if viable, is using **OpenStreetMap** as overlay/source for map.